# What i do wrong? Android JUnit

Tags: java, android, junit

I want stady junit. And create some test app, and then try test. I have simple activity, and in this activity i have method `checkEditText` this method return true or false. This is my activity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public boolean checkEditText(int number) {
        return number > 0 ? true : false;

    }
```

This is test:

```
package ac.junit2;


import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

import org.junit.Assert;

public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        MainActivity activity = getActivity();
        Assert.assertNotNull(activity);
    }



    public void testCheckNumber() {
        MainActivity activity = getActivity();

        boolean action = activity.checkEditText(0);
        assertTrue(action);
    }


}
```

I have error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:712)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:722)
    at ac.junit2.MainActivityTest.setUp(MainActivityTest.java:26)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Hm, It's not the edit text like the answers suggest. The `Assert.assertNotNull` in `MainActivityTest.setUp` fails already. I don't know how `getActivity()` is supposed to work but it's apparently not getting you anything.

Comment: The other thing I am wondering: dont you need a `@Test` annotation on your test methods? How is Junit supposed to know that it should call `testCheckNumber()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 0 is not greater than 0. So

```
return number > 0 ? true : false;
```

will return false when number is 0.

In the test, you are asserting true but the result is false.

Answer (score 1):

The test is failing, just as you programmed it to do. The result of `activity.checkEditText(0);` is `false` since you defined the method to return `false` unless the argument is *greater* than 0. Then in your test you are asserting that the result should be `true`.

Comment: The exception he has in his question is very clear: the fail already occurs in his `setUp()` method. Which means that the `getActivity()` call returned null. So your answer is not addressing current problem. Most likely, his actual test method is never called in the first place (or do you see a `@Test` annotation on it)?!

Comment: @Jägermeister - good point. Of course, the accepted answer has the same problem, does it not?

Comment: Sure. But he is the beginner with less than half a thousandth of your reputation ;-)

Comment: @Jägermeister - Which is beside the point. Other readers are going to see that answer and not read your comment to a different (and essentially identical) answer. It's also quite strange that OP marked the answer as the solution, since it doesn't, in fact, address the problem you pointed out.